# process not exiting when using gdi+ from dll

Tags: c++, windows, dll, shared-libraries, gdi+

I want to use GDI+ with Pascal scripting which doesn't provide GDI+ natively, but I don't know why When using dll(shared), the process will not exit even when the window is destroyed, I mean to say I can still see the process running from the task manager though it doesn't have any window to see. The process remains at idle i.e without any resource usage

In my dll, for every new hwnd i am hooking my own wndproc and on WM_Paint message i am drawing the specified objects that are so far are requested to be drawn

I am exporting DrawRectangle symbol for drawing and compiling for 32-bit
my dll is

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>
using namespace Gdiplus;
#include <objidl.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "Gdiplus.lib")

#include <functional>
#include <map>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

#define DLL_EXPORT(RETURN_TYPE)                                                \
  extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) RETURN_TYPE __stdcall

void msg(const char *str) { MessageBoxA(nullptr, str, "Message", 0); }
void msg(const wchar_t *str) { MessageBoxW(nullptr, str, L"Message", 0); }

class _GdiManager {
public:
  _GdiManager() {
    GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, nullptr);
  }
  ~_GdiManager() { GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken); }

private:
  GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
  ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;
} GdiManager;

class DrawableObject {
public:
  virtual void draw(Gdiplus::Graphics &Graphics) = 0;
  virtual ~DrawableObject() = default;
};

namespace DrawableObjects {
class Rectangle : public DrawableObject {
public:
  Rectangle(ARGB Color, int X, int Y, int Width, int Height)
      : m_X{X}, m_Y{Y}, m_Width{Width}, m_Height{Height}, m_Brush{Color} {}
  void draw(Gdiplus::Graphics &graphics) override {
    graphics.FillRectangle(&m_Brush, m_X, m_Y, m_Width, m_Height);
  }

private:
  int m_X, m_Y, m_Width, m_Height;
  Gdiplus::SolidBrush m_Brush;
};

} // namespace DrawableObjects

LRESULT MasterWindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

class Painter {
public:
  Painter(HWND hWnd) : m_WindowHandle{hWnd}, m_Graphics{hWnd} {
    m_OriginalWindowProc = (WNDPROC)GetWindowLongW(m_WindowHandle, GWL_WNDPROC);
    SetWindowLongW(m_WindowHandle, GWL_WNDPROC, (LONG)MasterWindowProc);
  }

  LRESULT CallOriginalWndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam,
                              LPARAM lParam) {
    return CallWindowProcW(m_OriginalWindowProc, hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
  }

  LRESULT Paint(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    if (uMsg == WM_PAINT) {
      for (auto &o : m_Objects)
        o->draw(m_Graphics);
    } else if (uMsg == WM_DESTROY) {
      PostQuitMessage(0);
    }
    return 0;
  }

  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<DrawableObject>> &Objects() { return m_Objects; }

private:
  HWND m_WindowHandle;
  Gdiplus::Graphics m_Graphics;
  WNDPROC m_OriginalWindowProc;
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<DrawableObject>> m_Objects;
};

std::map<HWND, std::unique_ptr<Painter>> windowPaint;

LRESULT MasterWindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
  auto &p = windowPaint[hwnd];
  auto r = p->CallOriginalWndProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
  p->Paint(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
  return r;
}

auto &insertPainter(HWND hwnd) {
  auto &my_painter = windowPaint[hwnd];
  if (!my_painter)
    my_painter = std::make_unique<Painter>(hwnd);
  return my_painter;
}

DLL_EXPORT(int)
DrawRectangle(HWND hwnd, ARGB LineColor, int startX, int startY, int width,
              int height) {
  auto &my_painter = insertPainter(hwnd);
  my_painter->Objects().push_back(std::make_unique<DrawableObjects::Rectangle>(
      LineColor, startX, startY, width, height));
  return 0;
}
```

the host program:

```
//#include "gdi.cpp"
#include <ObjIdl.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <cassert>
#include <gdiplus.h>
using namespace Gdiplus;
#pragma comment(lib, "Gdiplus.lib")

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

INT WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE, PSTR, INT iCmdShow) {
  HWND hWnd;
  MSG msg;
  WNDCLASS wndClass;

  wndClass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
  wndClass.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
  wndClass.cbClsExtra = 0;
  wndClass.cbWndExtra = 0;
  wndClass.hInstance = hInstance;
  wndClass.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
  wndClass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
  wndClass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
  wndClass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
  wndClass.lpszClassName = TEXT("GettingStarted");

  RegisterClass(&wndClass);

  hWnd = CreateWindow(TEXT("GettingStarted"),  // window class name
                      TEXT("Getting Started"), // window caption
                      WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,     // window style
                      CW_USEDEFAULT,           // initial x position
                      CW_USEDEFAULT,           // initial y position
                      CW_USEDEFAULT,           // initial x size
                      CW_USEDEFAULT,           // initial y size
                      NULL,                    // parent window handle
                      NULL,                    // window menu handle
                      hInstance,               // program instance handle
                      NULL);                   // creation parameters

  ShowWindow(hWnd, iCmdShow);
  UpdateWindow(hWnd);

  auto dll = LoadLibraryW(L"isGDI.dll");
  assert(dll);
  auto DrawRectangle = (int(__stdcall *)(
      HWND, DWORD, int, int, int, int))GetProcAddress(dll, "DrawRectangle");
  assert(DrawRectangle);
  DrawRectangle(hWnd, 0xffff0000, 0, 0, 100, 100);

  while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
  }
  FreeLibrary(dll);

  return msg.wParam;
} // WinMain

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam,
                         LPARAM lParam) {

  return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
} // WndProc
```

also, the program will work as expected if I call DrawRectangle directly through the source code (without using DLL)

Comment: in your code `GdiManager` is global object. as result it  constructor and destructor called from dll entry point. probably  call `GdiplusShutdown` from dll unload event hang. are you debug your code at all ? are it return from call `FreeLibrary(dll);` ?

Comment: Why are you using `isGDI.dll`, which is for Win95, instead of `gdiplus.dll`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i view that you use global object `GdiManager` inside dll. this meant that it destructor called from `DLL_PROCESS_DETACH`, so inside *LoaderLock* critical section. in destructor you call `GdiplusShutdown`. when `GdiplusShutdown` called inside *LoaderLock* and GDI+ use background thread ( `suppressBackgroundThread = FALSE` - this is your case) this is always cause deadlock:
`GdiplusShutdown` signal to background thread exit (set `Globals::ThreadQuitEvent`) and then **wait** for background thread exit. thread when exiting try enter to *LoaderLock* and hung here - because it hold by thread which call `GdiplusShutdown`. so main thread hung in wait for backgound thread and bacground thread hung in enter *LoaderLock* critical section.

we can try use `suppressBackgroundThread = TRUE`, but in this case need call [`NotificationUnhook`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/gdiplusinit/ns-gdiplusinit-gdiplusstartupoutput). if do this on `DLL_PROCESS_DETACH` already UB (based on implementation) this can look like ok, or hung, or fail (inside this called for example `DestroyWindow` which is also error from dll entry, also error if process detach will be called on different thread (compare dll attach) - so window will be created inside `NotificationHook` on another thread)

correct solution here will be export 2 additional functions from dll , say `Start` and `Stop`, and from first call `GdiplusStartup` and from second `GdiplusShutdown`. call `Start` just after dll load and `Stop` before unload

Comment: Thanks sir, now it's working (i am providing seperate method for gdishutdown)

Answer (score 0):

You are not telling the current thread (the app) to exit. Use [PostQuitMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-postquitmessage) in the `WndProc` associated with the window:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam,
                         LPARAM lParam) {
    if (message == WM_DESTROY)
         PostQuitMessage(0);
    else
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this too, but anyway `GdiplusShutdown` from `DLL_PROCESS_DETACH` (or more general from `LoaderLock`) always give deadlock. so simply fix with PostQuitMessage - correct but not enough